# Why is JOOQ restricted to Integer values and not Longs?

Tags: java, sql, integer, long-integer, jooq

I am new with **JOOQ** and it seems a little strange why it has many of my columns type-safed as Integers while they could easily need to be Longs in the near future.

Even `count(*)` results must be casted into Integers!

Is there a setting to have **Long as default** or any way to set **Long globally** in current project? (*wherever this may apply*)

If this is not possible.. Is there a reason to have it as Integer?'

this is a sample of some code in `Scala`:

```
def loggedInUserOwnsAccount(userId: Long) = {
selectCount().
  from(LOGGED_IN, EMAIL_ACCOUNT).
  where(LOGGED_IN.USER_ID.equal(EMAIL_ACCOUNT.PASS_ID)).
  and(LOGGED_IN.USER_ID.equal(userId.toInt)).asInstanceOf[ResultQuery[Record]]
}
```

Please note that the important part is that I **need** to convert Long to Int with this code `userId.toInt`, otherwise it will not compile

Comment: Apart from the [`DSL.count()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#count()) function, which could indeed return a `Long` rather than an `Integer`, what did you have in mind, i.e. what made you think that there is any such thing as a *"defaulted to Integer"*?

Comment: I just could not find an obvious way to change from `Integer` to `Long`. Having some methods taking a Long argument, now that I am migrating from hardcoded sql strings to jooq I would not like to change the interface. So I am now actually converting a Long to an Integer which could throw an exception if later the id is too large. Hope I covered you

Comment: Can you edit your question and show a practical example? I'm still not sure what the problem is...

Comment: Yep sure I just added a practical example. Thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your database, `LOGGED_IN.USER_ID` is probably of the SQL type `INT` which has its best equivalence in a Java `Integer` or a Scala `Int`. If you wanted to operate on a `Long`, you should change your database column's type to `BIGINT`.

There's no way around this "limitation", which is a good thing in my opinion. For instance, you cannot insert a `Long` into an `INT` database column. With [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), the Java / Scala compilers will prevent that from happening accidentally.

#### Workaround using implicit conversion

There is a workaround in Scala for this kind of problem. You can, of course try to apply implicit conversion by extending the existing [jOOQ-scala tools](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-scala/src/main/scala/org/jooq/scala/Conversions.scala).

```
trait SNumberField[T <: Number] extends SAnyField[T] {
  // [...]
  def equal(value : Number)        : Condition;
  def equal(value : Field[Number]) : Condition;
}

abstract class NumberFieldBase[T <: Number](override val underlying: Field[T])
    extends AnyFieldBase[T] (underlying)
    with SNumberField[T] {

  // [...]
  def equal(value : Number)
    = underlying.equal(underlying.getDataType().convert(value));
  def equal(value : Field[_ <: Number]) 
    = underlying.equal(value.coerce(underlying.getDataType());
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense. So I guess other kinds of database helpers let's call them like `anorm` are a little bit more loose on these constraints. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @GeorgePligor: Well, since you're in Scala land, I'm thinking that you might appreciate this kind of typesafety :-) Anyway, I've updated my answer with a possible workaround that you can apply to [jOOQ-scala's Conversion.scala](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-scala/src/main/scala/org/jooq/scala/Conversions.scala)

Comment: Is this dialect specific?  I generated code from an SQLite database and all of my Integer columns came in as Java ints.  Ints in SQLite can be up to 64 bit and SQLite does not have a long datatype.

Comment: @oillio: I'm not sure if the two things are related, but it's hard to say from a comment here on Stack Overflow. Would you mind asking a new question with some more details? I'll answer there...